# React native modal with list view item click

Tags: ios, react-native, modalviewcontroller

I want to pop a view modally when a list item is clicked.and been using this code it works fine if i dont scroll the list view and doesn't work at all if i scroll.

```
renderGymData(rowData){
return(
 <View>
         <Modal
             animationType={'none'}
             transparent={false}
             visible={!!this.state.selectedRow}>
             ....
         </Modal>

       <TouchableHighlight  onPress={() => this.showGymDetail(rowData)} >
         ....
       </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>);
}
and the render method of my list view is

render() {

    return (
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderGymData.bind(this)}
        style={styles.listView}>
      </ListView>
    );
```

}

I dont want to use navigator.push because i want the view to appear modally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use only a Modal, and render it bellow `ListView`, not inside `renderRow`, and pass row data to Modal when list item is clicked.

```
render() {
  return (
    <View>
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderGymData.bind(this)}
        style={styles.listView}>
      </ListView>
      <Modal
           animationType={'none'}
           transparent={false}
           visible={!!this.state.selectedRow}>
           ....
       </Modal>
    </View>
  );
}
```